# Handle function executed

Tags: javascript

im working on an upload script. im sending data with a method and im getting answer from another method. Example:

```
var a =new function(){
   this.start  = function(x,y,callback){

       this.finish = callback; /*php calls a.finish(someparams,moreparams)*/


   }
}
```

i want execute another function when a.finish executed. is that possible?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly assigning `callback` to `this.finish`, you can assign function which calls the other function and `callback`:

```
this.finish = function() {
    anotherFunction();
    callback.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: i have try this but there can be more parameters in callback function. or less...

Comment: Then use `callback.apply(this, arguments);`. You can do the same with the other function.